# How to do a midnight reboot of my Java app that runs on Heroku?

Tags: java, ruby, heroku

I maintain a Java app that runs on Heroku and I need to reboot it every 24 hours at around midnight.  I've been doing this off my laptop and need to switch to using the Heroku scheduler.  How to do it? I asked Heroku support and got this answer:

> What you probably want to do is setup a script that runs via the Heroku Scheduler. The script can use our Platform API to restart your dynos. You should be able to find a Java wrapper for the API if you do some searching (we don't provide an official Java wrapper client).
>
> Note that the Heroku Scheduler doesn't guarantee execution (there are some conditions where one might get skipped due to backend maintenance or other issues), so you probably would want to design your script to track whether a restart happened in the last 24 hours and have it run more frequently than once per day so if it's missed once it'll happen on the next run.

This "best effort" is fine for my needs.  My Java is rusty; how would I write this wrapper for the Heroku API and how would it be deployed?

Here are some related articles I found:

[Restart my heroku application automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986259/restart-my-heroku-application-automatically)

http://engineering.korrelate.com/2013/08/21/restart-heroku-dynos-on-your-terms/

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler

Comment: *Why* does the app need a reboot? That sounds like an underlying problem that needs fixing.

Comment: :-)  ... yes, there is an underlying problem that should be fixed, but apparently the fix is not trivial, and by "maintain" I mean that I perform more of an operations role, I don't do serious work on the code.  We need to keep the app going at this stage and can't really dig in deeply.