# Automatically restarting Heroku NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a NodeJS app hosted on Heroku. Is there a way for me to automatically run the "heroku restart" command every hour?

I found this answer but it looks like it's for a Rails project: [Restart my heroku application automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986259/restart-my-heroku-application-automatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, use the [Heroku SDK for Node.js](https://github.com/heroku/node-heroku-client).

Something like:

```
heroku.apps('my-app').dynos().restartAll()
```

Should do the trick. All of the dyno documentation can be found here: https://github.com/heroku/node-heroku-client/blob/master/docs/dyno.md. You can run a scheduled script using the Heroku scheduler.

I must warn you though, this is most certainly not the best way to do whatever you are trying to do. If you provide more insight into your problem I'm sure we can suggest something more appropriate than restarting your dynos all the time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Andrew - this worked for me. This was just for a temporary solution till we figured out what was wrong. Managed to figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Heroku v3 API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference) it is possible using the [request node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

```
var token = 'youAPIKeyHere';
var appName = 'yourAppName here';
var dynoName = 'yourDynoHere';

var request = require('request');

request.delete(
    {
        url: 'https://api.heroku.com/apps/' + appName + '/dynos/',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    },
    function(error, response, body) {
        // Do stuff
    }
);
```

---

There is also a [node wrapper](https://github.com/heroku/node-heroku-client) that provides a similar experience, but is poorly documented and requires an understanding of the [v3 API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference) anyway

```
var token = 'youAPIKeyHere';
var appName = 'yourAppName here';
var dynoName = 'yourDynoHere';

var Heroku = require('heroku-client');

var heroku = new Heroku({ token: token });
    heroku .delete('/apps/' + appName + '/dynos/' + dynoName)
           .then( x => console.log(x) );
```

---

I also found it useful to experiment in browser with this code

```
var token = 'youAPIKeyHere';
var appName = 'yourAppName here';
var dynoName = 'yourDynoHere';

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(
        'DELETE',
        'https://api.heroku.com/apps/' + appName + '/dynos/' + dynoName
    );
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        console.log(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.send();
```

---

- I personally did find using the delete method a bit concerning. Caution should be taken with using the `delete` method and the `/apps/$$appName$$` endpoint alone will delete the app. This is from personal experience
- For any of the above, if you omit the dyno name, you will restart all dynos under the app
- [The other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35931126/6539400) references a repo that is no longer supported