# Schedule Heroku to restart dynos every 10 or so minutes

Tags: node.js, heroku, scripting

I am developing a REST api with Node.js on Heroku, and one the drivers is giving me problems (I reported that to the driver creator already), but basically a restart of the dynos every half an hour or so seems to fix this. 
I was hoping y'all could help me with writing a script for scheduler or something similar to restart the dynos automatically every 10 or so minutes as a temporary fix.

p.s. I checked out the scheduler documentation, but it didn't make much sense

Thanks!

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986259/restart-my-heroku-application-automatically/45772205#45772205.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do what you're asking by doing the following:

- Create a script in your project that makes a Heroku Platform API request to restart your dynos. The API call documentation can be found here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#dyno-restart-all
- Provision the Heroku Scheduler addon.
- Go into Heroku Scheduler's web UI, and tell it to run your restart script every hour (or whatever time period works for you).

This is the best 'pragmatic' way to accomplish this.

Comment: Great idea. It worked but needed auth token. so added the steps in my answers.

Answer (score 30):

The steps provided by @rdegges require additional authentication token in the request. Adding more details:

1. Create Auth Token using Heroku CLI by running this command as mentioned on [Heroku platform API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-quickstart#authentication)

   `heroku authorizations:create`
2. Install the Heroku [Scheduler add-on](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/scheduler) into your Heroku application.
3. Open scheduler and go to add job. Enter the following command in the job editor. This command performs [restart the dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#dyno-restart-all).

`

```
curl -n -X DELETE https://api.heroku.com/apps/APP_NAME/dynos \n -H "Content-Type: application/json" \n -H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3" \n -H "Authorization: Bearer TokenCreatedInStep1"
```

Verify in the Heroku app logs, if the scheduler job is running on the set time.