# Running "heroku ps:restart" with Heroku Scheduler or in web interface console says "heroku: command not found"

Tags: heroku, scheduler, restart

I'm trying to have my dynos restarted every 2 hours or so. I don't have a CLI connection installed or anything like that, I'd like to do this directly in the web interface with Heroku Scheduler.

The web interface has a "Run console" option in the "More" menu.
[image: screenshot of the "Run console" input]

If I try to run the `heroku ps:restart` command there, it says:

```
bash: heroku: command not found
```

It's the same result if I try to  run just `ps:restart`.
And the same result if I put either of those in the Heroku Scheduler.

Is there a way for me to achieve this with Heroku Scheduler?
Without setting up extra scripts and authorizations etc. as described here: [Schedule Heroku to restart dynos every 10 or so minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43926740/schedule-heroku-to-restart-dynos-every-10-or-so-minutes)

Comment: Sidenote: from my experience you should invest time to fix the root problem, not just restart servers to fix it. (assuming it's a bug / memory problem / ...)

Comment: Thanks – I'm sure that's the right way to go, but I can't figure out the memory problems & my use case would allow for an hourly restart so conveniently :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default dyno image doesn't have the Heroku CLI installed. But there is [a buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-cli) you can add on top of your current language buildpack, and you'll have the heroku command in your app.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have the same issue, even if I followed the exact same steps outlined in the repo.