# using sys.exit() and heroku threw an error

Tags: python

```
2022-02-21T01:07:54.352381+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=_botname.herokuapp.com request_id=88df74f6-a5a1-4ee9-a0a5-c98a22a60949 fwd="115.66.143.26" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-02-21T01:07:54.988568+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=_botname.herokuapp.com request_id=5d73238d-8ee6-42d0-a010-997a073d06e9 fwd="115.66.143.26" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

- Got this error when using `sys.exit(26)` (trying to restart bot)

Comment: Have you tried using the heroku restart command: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-dyno-restart-dyno ?

Comment: it's actually for a bot, am making a restart command which is why i used sys.exit()

Comment: You could also try this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986259/restart-my-heroku-application-automatically/45772205#45772205

Comment: i did not understand anything in that thread